# Find a sequence of positive integers given an average

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a number $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ I want to find a sequence of positive integers $\{S_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that if $a_n$ is the average of the first $n$ terms, i.e:

$$ a_n := \displaystyle \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n S_k}{n} $$

then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=q $$

In particular, I'm interested in cases where $q > 1$ and the sequence is bounded.

And it would be nice if the sequences end up being a repeating sequence but it's not a requirement.

For example:

For $q = 2$, the sequence I want would be $\{2, 2, 2, \dots\}$

For $q = \frac{3}{2}$, it would be $\{2, 1, 2, 1, \dots \}$

For $q = \frac{4}{3}$, it would be $\{2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, \dots \}$

Now, both $\{3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, \dots \}$ and $\{2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, \dots \}$ work for $q = \frac{5}{3}$, I prefer the second one though, since its range is smaller ($1$ vs $2$).

All the previous sequences can be expressed as the repetition of a finite one: $\{2\}$, $\{2, 1\}$, $\{2, 1, 1\}$, $\{2, 2, 1\}$. Let's call these $s$

With $ q=\frac{n}{m} $ these kind of repeating sequences give:

$$|s| = m$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{|s|}s_k = n$$

Which gives a little hint, for a given $q = \frac{n}{m}$ it's enough to found $m$ positive integers such that their sum is $n$ (and remember $n>m$, so this is always possible: $\{n+1-m, \underbrace{1, \dots, 1}_{\textit{m-1 times}}\}$ solves the problem.

Now its range is terrible! $n-m$

Is there a way to find a solution of this form (a repeating sequence) with the minimal range possible?

I don't know if there're good solutions out there that are not repeating, but if I can generate them, those would suffice too.

Comment: Suppose $n \le q < n+1$. Then just repeat $n$ and $n+1$ the appropriate number of times

Comment: Uhm... I should've thought this through. Thanks!

Add the answer and I'll mark it as accepted!

Comment: thank you, but I'll just keep it as a comment. I don't like taking "free reputation". But don't worry, I've asked questions much worse than this before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that, unless $q$ is an integer, one cannot create a sequence with range $0$ (i.e. a constant sequence). However, one can always create a sequence with range $1$.

Let $q=\frac{m}{n}$. If we find a sequence of $n$ positive integers the sum of which is $m$, then certainly, upon extending this sequence periodically, its averages will have limit $q$. The main idea is to take elements "pretty close" to $q$ by using some $\lfloor q\rfloor$ and some $\lceil q\rceil$.

Let $m=an+b$ with $0\leq b<n$ so $q=a+\frac{b}{n}$. Now take

$$x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_b=a+1,\ \ x_{b+1}=\cdots=x_n=a.$$

Its sum is

$$b(a+1)+(n-b)a=an+b=m$$

and it consists only of the numbers $a$ and $a+1$, so it is a sequence with range $1$.